# Given a word from a list, I need to find all the next number values of the list

Tags: python, list

I am starting with python. Sorry if the question is trivial.

I have been searching, but I do not found any like my problem.

Given a word from a list, I need to find the first word that contains at least one number from the position of the given word.

For example, the given word is = CAR and my list is:

```
ls1 = ['MOTO', 'FREZZE', 'CAR', 'DECIDING', 'LOCAL', 'USING', '4587125', 'JOY', 'CAR', 'YORT', '548H21']
```

I expected to return:

```
ls2 = ['4587125','548H21']
```

I have been trying, but no results found...
Thanks for your help,

My code,

```
def hasNumbers(inputString):
 return any(char.isdigit() for char in inputString)

def number_word (character):
  while not hasNumbers(character):
    character = [ls1()[i + 1] for i, word in enumerate(ls1()[:-1]) if word == character]
    if hasNumbers(character):
        return character
```

Marcus

Comment: You should show your code to show what difficulties you are facing in your own implementation.

Comment: Can you tell us what tactic you're trying to use and why it doesn't work? Solving this problem is trivial, but we're not supposed to do your homework for you

Comment: @Metareven okey

Comment: @idjaw done, but I am realizing that it neither work for 1 word

Comment: You say you want the "first" word with numbers after "car", but your expected result contains two words. Do you want the first word with numbers after each instance of "car" in the list? What to return for `[1, car, foo, 2, 3, car, car, 4]`?

Comment: Yes, my expected result contains two numbers because, there are two words called "car". In your example, It has to return: ['2', '4', '4'] @tobias_k

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate the list and keep track how often you have seen the word, then when you see a number, yield it as often as you have seen the word before. You can make this a generator:

```
def get_nums_after(lst, word):
    seen = 0
    for x in lst:
        if x == word:
            seen += 1
        if any(c.isdigit() for c in x):
            while seen > 0:
                yield x
                seen -= 1
```

Examples:

```
ls1 = ['MOTO', 'FREZZE', 'CAR', 'DECIDING', 'LOCAL', 'USING', '4587125', 'JOY', 'CAR', 'YORT', '548H21']
print(list(get_nums_after(ls1, "CAR")))
# ['4587125', '548H21']
ls2 = ["1", "CAR", "FOO", "2", "3", "CAR", "CAR", "4"]
print(list(get_nums_after(ls2, "CAR")))
# ['2', '4', '4']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
given_word = "CAR"

words = ['MOTO', 'FREZZE', 'CAR', 'DECIDING', 'LOCAL', 'USING', '4587125', 'JOY', 'CAR', 'YORT', '548H21']

required_words = []
for i in range(len(words)):
    if given_word == words[i]:
        for j in word[i:]:
            if any(k.isdigit() for k in j)
                required_words.append(j)
                break
print required_words
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like :

```
>>> ls1 = ['MOTO', 'FREZZE', 'CAR', 'DECIDING', 'LOCAL', 'USING', '4587125', 'JOY', 'CAR', 'YORT', '548H21']
```

find the index of word `'CAR'` :

```
>>> ls2=[i for i in range(len(ls1)) if ls1[i]=='CAR']
>>> ls2
[2, 8]
```

Then create a temporary list that start to each `'CAR'` word in `ls1` and find the first string that contain a digit :

```
>>> ls4=[]
>>> for i in ls2:
...     ls3=ls1[i:]
...     for j in ls3:
...             if any(char.isdigit() for char in j):
...                     ls4.append(j)
...                     break
... 
>>> ls4
['4587125', '548H21']
```